# How can I detect when a select box is closed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, blur

I am using jquery and both blur and focusout functions require an extra click after the select box is closed to fire.  Is there another way to detect when the select box is immediately closed?

Comment: Post your code that you've tried

Comment: Would `onchange` work, or do you need to know when the select box is closed even if no change was made?

Comment: try `onchange` instead

Comment: You mean when you just click the down arrow to open, then again to close? Why do you need to trap that?

Comment: @RussellZahniser i would need to know when the select box is closed even if no change was made.

Comment: It doesnt seems to be possible with ordinary selectbox, but will work with custom html selectbox or make your own using ul li.

Answer (score 3):

As @samsquanch and @bfavaretto point out in comments here, there seems to be no way to reliably detect, across the current browser generation, when a select list is closed. Which is mildly mind-boggling, but there you are.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for ***[`.change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/)***. This will just after you choose any option.

```
$('select').on('change', function() {
  // code
});
```

And if you want to trigger a change event on page load just try:

```
$('select').on('change', function() {
  // code
}).change(); // trigger initial change
```

Comment: This won't work when the user opens and closes the box without choosing anything different.

Comment: Correct, I need something that knows when the select box closes when user does not choose a different option.

Comment: @heero Then your only object might be "click". But there's no way to know if the dropdown is closed or not, it's a black box. Unless you build your own dropdown with html+js.